# next-redux-wrapper: after hydration useSelector returns initial value (null), but getServerSideProps passes the correct value to the page

Tags: redux, next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit

I got getServerSideProps like this, which gets token from cookie and gets uses it to fetch user data with RTKQ endpoint. Then dispatches that data to authSlice.
So far it's good.

```
const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ req, res }: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
      let result: AuthState = null;

      const data = getCookie('device_access_token', { req, res });

      if (data?.toString()) {
        result = await store
          .dispatch(
            usersApi.endpoints.getUserByToken.initiate(data?.toString())
          )
          .unwrap();
      }
      if (result) store.dispatch(setUser(result));

      return { props: { auth: result } };
    }
);
```

Then I merge this auth data in the store like this:

```
const reducer = (state: ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    console.log('payload@HYDRATE', action.payload);

    const nextState = {
      ...state, // use previous state
      ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
    };
    if (state.auth.user) {
      nextState.auth.user = state.auth.user;
      nextState.auth.token = state.auth.token;
    } // preserve auth value on client side navigation

    return nextState;
  } else {
    return rootReducer(state, action);
  }
};
```

`console.log('payload@HYDRATE', action.payload);` also shows correct data.

The problem is in a page where I export `getServerSideProps`,

```
const IndexPage: NextPage = ({ auth }: any) => {
  console.log('user@index', auth);
  console.log('userSelect@index', useSelector(selectCurrentUser));

  return auth ? <Home /> : <NoAuthHome />;
};
```

`auth` shows correct value, but `useSelector(selectCurrentUser)` shows `null`

Can someone tell me if this is how it is intended to be, or I'm doing something wrong?

Because I don't want prop-drilling auth on countless pages, just use `useSelector(selectCurrentUser)` wherever necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem!

problem was in `_app.tsx`
I wrapped `<Component {...pageProps} />` with `<Provider store={store}` at the same time exporting with `wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)`